# Xcode adding new files to existing project in svn

Tags: ios, xcode, svn, commit, checkin

I have an existing project on svn and i want to commit a new ViewController class. My questions is along with the ViewController and .storyboard file do i also commit the project.pbxproj ? or is that not required.

Sorry about the silly question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to add  the files to the svn repository which have been changed or newly added. Files unchanged don't need to commit. When you select a file from `Source Control->Commit` it will show you the preview for changes occurred in the file. If you are adding a new file then you should add like this  `Source Control->Add`  & then commit.

about `project.pbxproj`  you don't need to commit this file if it already exists in repository

Answer (score 2):

Right click the new files,  click **Source Control -> Add**

Then right click again ,  click **Source Control -> Commit Selected Files**

Thats it.