# Adding files to an Xcode project (SVN)

Tags: xcode, svn

I "checked out" an SVN repo. The repo contains a few Xcode projects and a workspace. I can open the workspace, build everything, run the app etc. If I make changes to any existing file they will be taken into account when building the app.

Now I want to add two new files to the workspace/project. I want to modify these files and when ready "commit" and "push" (I normally use git) the files to the repo. I added `MyClass.h` and `MyClass.m` to the Xcode project via right clicking on the appropriate group in Xcode and selecting "Add file to MyProject...".

The project won't build because `MyClass.h` can't be found. I also see a warning from the workspace that "MyClass.h is missing from the working copy".

**How can I add files to an Xcode project under SVN version control?**

I tried the suggestions here [Xcode adding new files to existing project in svn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15421386/xcode-adding-new-files-to-existing-project-in-svn) but nothing works yet. For example when the files I just added to Xcode are selected the menu option "Add Selected Files" in the Source Control menu is greyed out.

I'm using Xcode 5.

Comment: Hi Guys, if any one have any idea about it, please share..

Answer (score 0):

As a work around, you can use smartsvn which has options for adding and removing files in Modify  top menu